# how to insert results of a queryset to a table in Django

Tags: django

Am trying to insert results of a queryset into another table in my views but I get the error:

```
  TypeError at /trackdata/
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ValuesQuerySet'
```

The code is this:

```py
def trackdata(request):
    usbtrack=(Usb.history.values('evidence'))
    recordscount=Usb.history.values('evidence').count()
    update=Evidence_source(evidence=usbtrack,frequency=recordscount,datatype='tzworksusb')
    update.save()
```

Comment: Is this the whole code of the trackdata? cause the problem lies somewhere you do a conversion using `int()` call

Comment: yes thats the whole code for that function..evidence has been declared as charfield in the models though.

Comment: What i want to achieve is to insert a result of a queryset to another table..i want to insert the results of usbtrack and recordcount above into Evidence_source

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `history` is and what you are trying to fetch because your QuerySet should be formed as `Usb.objects.filter(evidence=request.POST['evidence']).values('evidence')`, for example.  See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values).

Anyway, `values('evidence')` returns a list of dicts (e.g. `[{'evidence': some_value,}]`), so you'd need to change `evidence=usbtrack` to something like `evidence=usbtrack[0]['evidence']`.  You should probably use try/except and other error checking code, as well as loops because QuerySets by definition return lists, even if there is only one row in the result set. Another alternative is `values_list()` with `flat=True`, which returns a list of your query results rather than dicts:

```
usbtrack = Usb.objects.filter(evidence=request.POST['evidence']).values_list('evidence', flat=True)
Evidence_source(evidence=usbtrack[0], frequency=usbtrac.count(), datatype='tzworksusb')
```

Finally, if I guessed your intentions correctly and you are passing 'evidence' in your request, you would simply just do this:

```
usbtrack_count = Usb.objects.filter(evidence=request.POST['evidence']).count()
Evidence_source(evidence=request.POST['evidence'], frequency=usbtrack_count, datatype='tzworksusb')
```